# Deserialize JSON structure

Tags: c#, json, parsing, deserialization

This is the code:

```
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            GResponse dict = jss.Deserialize<GResponse>(jsonText);
```

Those are the classes:

```
public class GResponse
{
    public List<GResponseData> responseData { get; set; }
    public string responseDetails { get; set; }
    public int responseStatus { get; set; }

}

public class GResponseData
{
    public List<GResult> results { get; set; }
    public List<GCursor> cursor { get; set; }
}

public class GResult
{
    public string GsearchResultClass { get; set; }
    public string unescapedUrl { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string visibleUrl { get; set; }
    public string cacheUrl { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string titleNoFormatting { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class GCursor
{
    public string resultCount { get; set; }
    public List<GPages> PagesItems { get; set; }
    public string estimatedResultCount { get; set; }
    public int currentPageIndex { get; set; }
    public string moreResultsUrl { get; set; }
    public string searchResultTime { get; set; }
}
public class GPages
{
    public string start { get; set; }
    public int label { get; set; }
}
```

I have been trying to deserialize the following json string without success for quite some time.

```
{
    "responseData": {
        "results": [
            {
                "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                "unescapedUrl": "irrelevant",
                "url": "irrelevant",
                "visibleUrl": "irrelevant",
                "cacheUrl": "irrelevant",
                "title": "irrelevant",
                "titleNoFormatting": "irrelevant",
                "content": "irrelevant"
            },
            {
                "GsearchResultClass": "GwebSearch",
                "unescapedUrl": "irrelevant",
                "url": "irrelevant",
                "visibleUrl": "irrelevant",
                "cacheUrl": "irrelevant",
                "title": "irrelevant",
                "titleNoFormatting": "irrelevant",
                "content": "irrelevant"
            }
        ],
        "cursor": {
            "resultCount": "irrelevant",
            "pages": [
                {
                    "start": "0",
                    "label": 1
                },
                {
                    "start": "28",
                    "label": 8
                }
            ],
            "estimatedResultCount": "irrelevant",
            "currentPageIndex": 0,
            "moreResultsUrl": "irrelevant",
            "searchResultTime": "0.27"
        }
    },
    "responseDetails": null,
    "responseStatus": 200
}
```

No errors seem to appear whatsoever but when I check the dict.responseData.Count it is always equal to 0 for some reason. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `resonseData` is list you should also have it as list/array in your JSON, so change:

```
"responseData": {
   "results": ...
   "cursor: ...
}
```

to array, that contains one element:

```
"responseData": [
    {
        "results": ...
        "cursor: ...
    }
]
```

Comment: If you cant change responseData to array in JSON then change it's type from `List<GResponseData>` to `GResponseData` in C#

Answer (score 1):

Copy your Json. Go to Visual Studio then Edit > Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes. You will now see what your Json looks like deserialized to c# and can then adjust your existing c# classes accordingly.

Note: You must have a C# file open to get the "Paste Special" option up along with some valid JSON in your clipboard (copied).